# Pandas read_sql DataTypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I have to compare two data sources to see if the same record is the same across all rows. One data source comes from an Excel File, where another comes from a SQL Table. I tried using [`DataFrame.equals()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) Like i have in the past.

However, the issue is due to pesky datatype issues. Even though the data *looks* the same, the datatypes are making `excel_df.loc[excel_df['ID'] = 1].equals(sql_df.loc[sql_df['ID'] = 1])` return `False`. Here is an example of the datatype from `pd.read_excel()`:

```
COLUMN ID                         int64
ANOTHER Id                      float64
SOME Date                datetime64[ns]
Another Date             datetime64[ns]
```

The same columns from `pd.read_sql`:

```
COLUMN ID                        float64
ANOTHER Id                       float64
SOME Date                         object
Another Date                      object
```

I could try using the `converters` argument from [`pd.read_excel()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) to match SQL. Or also doing `df['Column_Name] = df['Column_Name].astype(dtype_here)` But I am dealing with a lot of columns. Is there an easier way to check for values across all columns?

checking [`pd.read_sql()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) there is no thing like `converters` but I'm looking for something like:

```
df = pd.read_sql("Select * From Foo", con, dtypes = ({Column_name: str,
                                                      Column_name2:int}))
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
excel_df = pd.read_excel(...)
sql_df = pd.read_sql(...)

# attempt to cast all columns of excel_df to the types of sql_df
excel_df.astype(sql_df.dtypes.to_dict()).equals(sql_df)
```

Comment: I wish this would've worked. I get `TypeError: data type not understood`

Comment: This answer did lead me to a semi-usable answer. I created a loop and this does not return the `TypeError`. However, I did have to change some datatypes (like dates and zip codes to `str` that were being read as `int`). If you would like to update your answer, I can accept it for the community. Here is what I found: `for column in df1.columns.tolist():
    df1[column] = df1[column].astype(sql_df[column].dtype)` Proper indentation must be used.

Comment: @Matt, which Pandas version are you using?

Comment: Also, can you guarantee that the columns of both data frames are identical? (i.e. all columns of `excel_df` are columns of `sql_df` and vice-versa)

Comment: version `0.20.2` and yes, the columns will always match

Comment: @Matt, strange, I can't reproduce your error (at least for float-to-int and string-to-datetime conversion like you've posted in your question). Can you provide the full `dtypes` for both data frames you are working with?

Comment: @Matt, actually, I am using 0.20.3, and it looks like this patch fixed a bug related to passing a `Series` to `DataFrame.astype`. I've made a small edit in my answer to explicitly convert the `dtypes` series into a dictionary. Can you please try it out?

Comment: For reference, here is the [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16717).

Answer (score -1):

If you are seeing "Object" dtype that means that pandas can't interpret some of the rows as dates so instead in casts the whole column as Object (which is basically string)

Looking at documentation for dtypes, converters and parse_dates arguments:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

You can also check dayfirst argument to parse the dates correctly.